# How to focus the child control when Tab is pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, tabindex

I have a custom `TextBox` control and this control has a windows default `TextBox` control inside of it. Since it has a child control when Tab is pressed, the cursor doesn't focus directly to the child control. It is required to double press the Tab key.So first Tab is going to the parent and second is to the child. How can I do it by one Tab press?

**Custom TextBox is:**

```
    class MyTextBox : Control
    {
        TextBox innerBox;
        public MyTextBox()
        {
            //.....
            innerBox = new TextBox();
            Controls.Add(innerBox);
            innerBox.Parent = this;
            innerBox.TabIndex = this.TabIndex;
            //.....
        }
        //.....
    }
```

Comment: Change the base class to UserControl.  Or change it to TextBox and don't add an "innerbox" at all.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, It worked. Would you mind to explain why `UserControl` solves the problem?

Comment: It was designed to be a container for child controls, the Control class was not.  Look at the [UserControl.WndProc() method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UserControl.cs,f9a8bf95a2d28b6e) to see how it does it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabindex` attribute, and specify the child as `tabindex="1"`. this would make the markup for the child control something similar to

`<input type="textbox" runat="server" id="TB_id" tabindex="1"></input>`

Comment: I have noticed that I have a tag mistake in the question. Sorry about that. Actually,it is a winform question